# Java applet acting strange in safari

Tags: java, plugins, safari

I'm working on some java stuff and the applet I made runs funny on safari. When I run it with Firefox it works fine though... So for mac users who can test this, if anyone knows why, any help would be appreciated. [here's the link](http://www.ahmadabdul3.com/rpgpractice.html)
thank you!!

Comment: Show the code...I wont run your code without seeing it first

Comment: Did you try it in Safari on Windows?

Comment: no I haven't, I just tried it on chrome in windows and its acting strange on windows too... I'll add my code soon, I'm busy at the moment, thanks for the responses.